# When should we override WindowProc and when should we override DefWindowProc?

Tags: windows-messages

My doubt is that,

1. in what all situations we should override `WindowProc`?
2. in what all situations we should override `DefWindowProc`?

Environment: VC++, MFC

Comment: What platform are you using? In WPF ideally never. In WinForms most WindowProc functionality is provided for you, ditto MFC.

Comment: It is VC++. Question is updated.

Comment: Are you using MFC or another Win32 wrapper like WTL or WFC, or using Win32's C-style API directly?

Comment: I am using MFC.